# I have a problem when using VideoJS with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, video.js

When using VideoJS the video works fine and all But it doesn't show me the options for the available sources as it should.

I tried using A plugins for the sources and it still doesn't show, Idk what's or why it's doing that maybe I'm using it in the wrong way or perhaps the sources is automatically hidden by default or it's just bugged.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

> My Code
> NOTE: Sources comes from another Component and It's been tested it should work find when used.

```
import React from 'react';

import videojs from 'video.js';
import 'video.js/dist/video-js.css';

import "videojs-hotkeys";

export const VideoJS = (props) => {
  const videoRef = React.useRef(null);
  const playerRef = React.useRef(null);
  const {options, onReady} = props;
  React.useEffect(() => {

    // Make sure Video.js player is only initialized once
    if (!playerRef.current) {
      // The Video.js player needs to be _inside_ the component el for React 18 Strict Mode. 
      const videoElement = document.createElement("video-js");

      videoElement.classList.add('vjs-big-play-centered');
      videoRef.current.appendChild(videoElement);

      const player = playerRef.current = videojs(videoElement, options, () => {
        videojs.log('player is ready');
        onReady && onReady(player);
      });
    // You could update an existing player in the `else` block here
    // on prop change, for example:
    } else {
      const player = playerRef.current;

      player.autoplay(options.autoplay);
      player.src(options.sources);
    }
  }, [onReady, options, videoRef]);

  // Dispose the Video.js player when the functional component unmounts
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const player = playerRef.current;

    return () => {
      if (player && !player.isDisposed()) {
        player.dispose();
        playerRef.current = null;
      }
    };
  }, [playerRef]);

  return (
    <div className='w-100 h-100' data-vjs-player >
      <div ref={videoRef}  className='w-100 h-100' />
    </div>
  );
}
export default function Videojs({sources}){

// Video Options
  const videoJsOptions = {
    responsive: true,
    controls: true,
    playbackRates: [0.5, 1, 1.5, 2],
    preload: 'auto',
    plugins: {
        hotkeys: {
        volumeStep: 0.1,
        seekStep: 5,
        enableModifiersForNumbers: false
        }
    },
    sources: sources.map(item => {
      return {
        src: item.url,
        type: item.isM3U8 && 'application/x-mpegURL',
        quality: item.quality
      }
    })
  }
  
  return(
    <div className='h-100 w-100'>
      <VideoJS options={videoJsOptions} />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: To achieve this, you'll need to use the videojs-contrib-quality-levels and videojs-hls-quality-selector plugins as far as I know. LE: after a little researach I found other plugin more up to date: videojs-resolution-switcher plugin

Comment: Thanks, But I already tried plugins,
`videojs-contrib-quality-levels` Doesn't work.
`videojs-hls-quality-selector` Doesn't support HLS
And `videojs-resolution-switcher` When trying to install it using NPM it gives me an Error.
```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
```

Answer (score 0):

Viper, I am aware now that you tried the plugins I specified earlier and you remembered me of an old project of mine where I got a similar problem and what I made was the following. (Note that this was a solution for me some time ago)

<-- old code removed -->

This should work but you have to adapt it to display available source options.

LE: I've tried to update the code based on videojs [documentation](https://videojs.com/guides/videojs-7-to-8/) as videojs.extend() method has been removed on latest versions.

<-- new code here -->

```
import videojs from 'video.js';

const SourceSelector = videojs.extend(videojs.getComponent('MenuButton'), {
  constructor: function (player, options) {
    videojs.getComponent('MenuButton').apply(this, arguments);
    this.controlText('Source');
  },

  createItems: function () {
    const player = this.player();
    const sources = player.options().sources;
    const currentSourceIndex = sources.findIndex(
      (source) => source.src === player.currentSrc()
    );

    const items = sources.map((source, index) => {
      return new videojs.MenuItem(player, {
        label: source.quality || source.type,
        index: index,
        selected: index === currentSourceIndex,
      });
    });

    return items;
  },

  buildCSSClass: function () {
    return 'vjs-source-selector vjs-menu-button vjs-menu-button-popup     vjs-control vjs-button';
  },
});
```

Comment: Should I add the event listener to `VideoJS` or the `Videojs` Component?

Comment: I think I'm doing something wrong,
I tried doing what you just said but it gives me an error now.
Could you please explain to me more or show me how the code is supposed to be applied?

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ehQduOJhZuaF

Comment: Yea, so based on their documentation, they removed  `videojs.extend()` method. check this https://videojs.com/guides/components/ and this https://videojs.com/guides/videojs-7-to-8/  above you can find an adapted code for this issue. hope it helps you.